# How to display the result in another form?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio

I am a newbie to c# coding. I wanted to know that how can i pass the values of the string str1 to another form and display it in another windows form from the below code. Well i can display it in a messagebox as "MessageBox.Show(str1);" but i want to pass the value of str1 and display it in another form.

```
enter code here

<pre> <code>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MyExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

namespace Loans
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Select an Excel File";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"d:\test";
        fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;





        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("selected file is :" + fdlg.FileName);

        }

        MyExcel.Application xlApp;
        MyExcel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        MyExcel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        MyExcel.Range range;

        string cellValue;
        int rCnt;
        int cCnt;
        int rw = 0;
        int cl = 0;

        Loans.Form2 frm = new Loans.Form2();


        xlApp = new MyExcel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@fdlg.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (MyExcel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        rw = range.Rows.Count;
        cl = range.Columns.Count;

        //MessageBox.Show("Working");
        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
        {
            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
            {

                string str = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, "N"] as MyExcel.Range).Value2);

                if (str == "3" || str == "4" || str == "5" || str == "6" || str == "7")
                {
                    string str1 = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as MyExcel.Range).Value2);
                    MessageBox.Show(str1); //want to display the values
                                           //of str1 in a seperate form  


                }


            }
        }



        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

    }

    public void Show(string text)
    {

        this.Show();
    }




    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to send the string in the constructor of the second form. Also, you can put a label in your second form and to save the string in that label:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string _stringToShow;
    public Form2(string stringToShow)
    {
        _stringToShow = stringToShow;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = _stringToShow;
    }
}
```

And from the first form I called the second form:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Ll = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        string concatenate = string.Join(" ", Ll.ToArray());
        new Form2(concatenate ).Show();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. i did try for it and i am getting an error as -->                                                                                                cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Comment: What values are you sending there ? It seems that you're making a bad conversion between a list and a string. I added on the solution the code for the first window too.

Comment: I am retrieving the cell values from the excel file and storing them in a string list. Now that i want to display the retrieved values in the second form. I am not using a textbox.

Comment: You can concatenate that values from the List in a single string and then send that string in the constructor of the second form and then follow my example from the solution for the Form 2. I edited the Form1 with an example of concatenation and sending the result string to the Form2.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a variable on your second form that will be set on your first form:

Add this on your second form (form that will receive the message)

```
public string strVariable { get; set; }
```

Then on your first form, declare the variable before showing it:

```
   Form2 frm = new Form2();
   frm.strVariable = "Hello World";
   frm.Show();
```

Upon loading of second form (receiver), you can access the data and show it to the user, in this case, a label for example upon form load:

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = strVariable;
    }
```